# How to split tab-delimited array into two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array

```
array=["product1    250","product2    500","product3    750"]
```

Blank spaces represent tab.
I want to split array like this..

```
array_1=["product1","product2","product3"]

array_2=["250","500","750"]
```

How can i do this using Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote pretty much the same answer as @thefoureye, but instead I am using an object to store the results.

```
var result = yourArray.reduce(function(acumulator, current) {
    var values = current.split('\t');

    acumulator.products.push(values[0]);
    acumulator.prices.push(values[1]);

    return acumulator;
}, { products: [], prices: [] })

console.log(result.products, result.prices);
```

#### Another way (maybe simpler)

```
var array1 = [], array2 = [];

yourArray.forEach(function(item) {
    var values = item.split('\t');

    array1.push(values[0]);
    array2.push(values[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get them as an array of arrays, by splitting and gathering the split strings in an array of array with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and you can access the individual arrays with their corresponding index, like this

```
var array = ["product1    250", "product2    500", "product3    750"];

var arrays = array.reduce(function(result, currentItem) {
    var splits = currentItem.split(/\s+/);
    result[0].push(splits[0]);
    result[1].push(splits[1]);
    return result;
}, [[], []]);

console.log(arrays[0], arrays[1]);
# [ 'product1', 'product2', 'product3' ] [ '250', '500', '750' ]
```

If needed, you can assign the first and second elements to different variables, like this

```
var array_1 = arrays[0], array_2 = arrays[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through each cell in the array, and call `split("\t");` on the value. Then pass the return to each array. (Assumes the the tabs are actual `\t` and not just an amount of whitespace)